# What does 'sp' mean in an asm clobber list?

Tags: assembly, llvm, clang

I'm struggling to get some x86 assembly to compile on a Core 2 Duo Mac. Using clang returns an `invalid operand` error for statements like the following:

```
asm volatile ("subl %0,%%esp" :: "r"(foobar) : "cc", "sp");
```

Where `foobar` is a `long`. I was wondering what the `sp` keyword means in the clobber list as neither the GCC / llvm doc nor Google can shed much light on them. Does anybody know of a comprehensive list of clobber keywords?

Comment: "clobber keywords" are register names. Maybe instead of `"sp"` you want to specify `"esp"`.

Comment: I realise you can explicitly specify registers but the [documentation](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3) says GAS also supports keywords like "memory" and "cc". No word on "sp" though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [gcc-4.4.3/gcc/config/i386/i386.h :2036](http://google.com/codesearch#qoCVjtE_vOw/gcc4/trunk/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/config/i386/i386.h&q=x86%20%22%5C%22sp%5C%22%22&exact_package=http://mosync.googlecode.com/svn&type=cs&l=2036) file I conclude that "sp" is gcc-specific alias of "esp":

```
/* How to refer to registers in assembler output.
   This sequence is indexed by compiler's hard-register-number (see above).  */

/* In order to refer to the first 8 regs as 32-bit regs, prefix an "e".
   For non floating point regs, the following are the HImode names.

   For float regs, the stack top is sometimes referred to as "%st(0)"
   instead of just "%st".  PRINT_OPERAND handles this with the "y" code.  */

#define HI_REGISTER_NAMES                                               \
{"ax","dx","cx","bx","si","di","bp","sp",                               \
 "st","st(1)","st(2)","st(3)","st(4)","st(5)","st(6)","st(7)",          \
 "argp", "flags", "fpsr", "fpcr", "frame",                              \
 "xmm0","xmm1","xmm2","xmm3","xmm4","xmm5","xmm6","xmm7",               \
 "mm0", "mm1", "mm2", "mm3", "mm4", "mm5", "mm6", "mm7",                \
 "r8", "r9", "r10", "r11", "r12", "r13", "r14", "r15",                  \
 "xmm8", "xmm9", "xmm10", "xmm11", "xmm12", "xmm13", "xmm14", "xmm15"}

#define REGISTER_NAMES HI_REGISTER_NAMES

/* Table of additional register names to use in user input.  */

#define ADDITIONAL_REGISTER_NAMES \
{ { "eax", 0 }, { "edx", 1 }, { "ecx", 2 }, { "ebx", 3 },       \
  { "esi", 4 }, { "edi", 5 }, { "ebp", 6 }, { "esp", 7 },       \
  { "rax", 0 }, { "rdx", 1 }, { "rcx", 2 }, { "rbx", 3 },       \
  { "rsi", 4 }, { "rdi", 5 }, { "rbp", 6 }, { "rsp", 7 },       \
  { "al", 0 }, { "dl", 1 }, { "cl", 2 }, { "bl", 3 },           \
  { "ah", 0 }, { "dh", 1 }, { "ch", 2 }, { "bh", 3 } }
```

Both "sp" and "esp" (and "rsp" too) will code register number 7.

So, this code is legal for GCC; but is you want to make it portable (compilable by clang), change "sp" to "esp". This patch will not change gcc logic and will enable you to build this with clang.

== Update==

there is a possibility that gcc stores size of register access for clobbers too. Here is the the checker function of asm registers - clobbers conflict (gcc/stmt.c):

```
tree_conflicts_with_clobbers_p (tree t, HARD_REG_SET *clobbered_regs)
{
  /* Conflicts between asm-declared register variables and the clobber
     list are not allowed.  */
  tree overlap = tree_overlaps_hard_reg_set (t, clobbered_regs);
```

The conflict (overlap) is checked via HARD_REG_SET, which has size 52 bits:

[gcc/hard-reg-set.h :50](http://www.google.com/codesearch#H0QEcOqkK2U/gcc-4.5/gcc/hard-reg-set.h&q=HARD_REG_SET%20&exact_package=svn://sources.blackfin.uclinux.org/toolchain/trunk&type=cs&l=50). Hard_reg_set has length of FIRST_PSEUDO bits, rounded up to fill fastint fully.

```
#define HARD_REG_SET_LONGS \
 ((FIRST_PSEUDO_REGISTER + HOST_BITS_PER_WIDEST_FAST_INT - 1)   \
  / HOST_BITS_PER_WIDEST_FAST_INT)
typedef HARD_REG_ELT_TYPE HARD_REG_SET[HARD_REG_SET_LONGS];
```

[i386/i386.h :865](http://google.com/codesearch#qoCVjtE_vOw/gcc4/trunk/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/config/i386/i386.h&q=x86%20%22%5C%22sp%5C%22%22&exact_package=http://mosync.googlecode.com/svn&type=cs&l=865): `#define FIRST_PSEUDO_REGISTER 53`

[:882 same file](http://google.com/codesearch#qoCVjtE_vOw/gcc4/trunk/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/config/i386/i386.h&q=x86%20%22%5C%22sp%5C%22%22&exact_package=http://mosync.googlecode.com/svn&type=cs&l=882) has a list of registers in the HARD_REG_SET:

```
#define FIXED_REGISTERS                                         \
/*ax,dx,cx,bx,si,di,bp,sp,st,st1,st2,st3,st4,st5,st6,st7*/      \
{  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,       \
/*arg,flags,fpsr,fpcr,frame*/                                   \
    1,    1,   1,   1,    1,                                    \
/*xmm0,xmm1,xmm2,xmm3,xmm4,xmm5,xmm6,xmm7*/                     \
     0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,                      \
/* mm0, mm1, mm2, mm3, mm4, mm5, mm6, mm7*/                     \
     0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,                      \
/*  r8,  r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15*/                     \
     2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,                      \
/*xmm8,xmm9,xmm10,xmm11,xmm12,xmm13,xmm14,xmm15*/               \
     2,   2,    2,    2,    2,    2,    2,    2 }
```

So register-clobber conflict is checked without size field check (for non-mm/xmm regs).

Comment: Good call, never thought to look there. I have a few other issues with my 'port' but the inline assembly is compiling anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Surely that would be the stack pointer, *especially* since you're actually subtracting something from the stack pointer `esp`. You probably already know this bit but, just in case, the `cc` is the condition code register (the flags and so forth).

Why it's `sp` and not `esp`, I couldn't tell you but, if you're getting errors, that's the first thing I'd change to see if that was the problem.

The values that you're supposed to be able to put in there are all the registers that may be clobbered (other than those explicitly listed for output which `gcc` already knows will change) and the special value `memory` if you don't want `gcc` to assume any cached memory values will remain valid.

The registers, of course, depend on the underlying architecture. Not sure that's a *comprehensive* list but it's all I've ever used, or needed to use.

Comment: That was exactly what I assumed until I read the rather poorly documented examples. The code works on x86 linux and I'm wondering if it's something to do with the Darwin stack alignment. I'm a bit surprised that there's no GCC reference for all these keywords in though...

Comment: sp is a register on x86; it's the bottom 16 bits of esp.

Comment: @servn, I got that, but the instruction can potentially change _all_ of `esp`, not just the lower bits. That's why I questioned whether it should be `esp`.